# Processing multiple csv tables at once and pasting results on a new column

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm learning how to use `for` loops in R but this once seems a bit to complex for what I can do.

I've a few files with a name format `"collar41361_41365.0.x.csv"`, and would like to do a series of calculations which results would be on a new column in the same file.

I've been succesful at doing this for one file at the time, but would like to automat the process for all `"collar41361_41365.0.x.csv"` files.

Here's a small sample of how `"collar41361_41365.0.x.csv"` files look like:

```
> collaraccuracy<-fread("collar41361_41365.0.8.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)
> print(collaraccuracy)
      V1  observed predicted probability results1 results2       results
  1:   1   Head-up Vigilance   0.2727273 NEGATIVE     TRUE TRUE_NEGATIVE
  2:   2   Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE     TRUE TRUE_NEGATIVE
  3:   3   Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE     TRUE TRUE_NEGATIVE
  4:   4   Head-up   Grazing   0.5454545 NEGATIVE     TRUE TRUE_NEGATIVE
  5:   5   Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE     TRUE TRUE_NEGATIVE
```

I need to count the total number of `"TRUE_POSITIVES"` (TP), `"FALSE_POSITIVES"` (FP), `"TRUE_NEGATIVES"` (TN) and `"FALSE_NEGATIVES"` (FN) and compute a series of measures such as:

1) accuracy = (tn+tp)/(tn+tp+fn+fp)

2) precision = tp/(tp+fp)

3) recall = tp/(tp+fn)

This is how I proceed when analyzing a single file:

```
collaraccuracy<-fread("collar41361_41365.0.8.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)
tp<-length(grep("TRUE_POSITIVE", collaraccuracy$results))
fp<-length(grep("FALSE_POSITIVE", collaraccuracy$results))
tn<-length(grep("TRUE_NEGATIVE", collaraccuracy$results))
fn<-length(grep("FALSE_NEGATIVE", collaraccuracy$results))


accuracy = (tn+tp)/(tn+tp+fn+fp)
accuracy
precision = tp/(tp+fp)
precision
recall = tp/(tp+fn)
recall
```

I would like to create an `for` loop that will:

1) Read all files with name format `"collar41361_41365.0.x.csv"` and calculate `accuracy`, `precision` and `recall` values for every single one.

2) Create three new columns for each file with headers `"accuracy"`, `"precision"` and `"recall"`, and paste the result of the formula under.

Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Not sure I fully understand the intended output

```
# setwd('') # to folder where your csv files are
# change 'file.csv' to 'collar41361_41365.0'
f <- list.files(path = getwd(), full.names = F, pattern = 'file.csv')

dfs <- list()
for(i in 1:length(f)){
  collaraccuracy <- data.table::fread(f[i],stringsAsFactors = F)
  tp <- length(grep("TRUE_POSITIVE", collaraccuracy$results))
  fp <- length(grep("FALSE_POSITIVE", collaraccuracy$results))
  tn <- length(grep("TRUE_NEGATIVE", collaraccuracy$results))
  fn <-length(grep("FALSE_NEGATIVE", collaraccuracy$results))

  # append the results to the files 
  collaraccuracy$accuracy <- (tn+tp)/(tn+tp+fn+fp)
  collaraccuracy$precision <- tp/(tp+fp)
  collaraccuracy$recall <- tp/(tp+fn)

  # you make way to write them to a different directory
  data.table::fwrite(collaraccuracy, file = paste0('new',f[i]))
}
```